# How to avoid loading UI5 controls as single modules?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-basis

In SAPUI5, when you add a `sap.m.DatePicker` to your app for the first time, it takes some seconds to load the required files and open the date picker. In the [`DatePicker` API](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker), they explained:

> **Note:** The application developer should add dependency to `sap.ui.unified` library on application level to ensure that the library is loaded before the module dependencies will be required. The `sap.ui.unified.Calendar` is used internally only if the `DatePicker` is opened (not used for the initial rendering). If the `sap.ui.unified` library is not loaded before the `DatePicker` is opened, it will be loaded upon opening. This could lead to CSP compliance issues and adds an additional waiting time when the `DatePicker` is opened for the first time. To prevent this, apps using the `DatePicker` should also load the `sap.ui.unified` library in advance.

So this is the solution they suggest for making the loading of `DatePicker` faster.

When I use `sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable`, it takes at least 10 to 15 seconds for the first time until the user can see the app.

Actually, it loads a huge number of individuals JavaScript files. Here is a small part of the files that are loaded.

[image: Here is a small part of the files that are loaded.]

**Now the question is: is there anyway to make this loading faster?**

I tried adding `"sap.ui.comp"` to the the `/sap.ui5/dependencies/libs` section of manifest, but was not really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SmartTable` is a huge control that has a direct dependency to the following libraries:

- `"sap.ui.core"`
- `"sap.ui.comp"`
- `"sap.m"`
- `"sap.ui.table"`
- Transitively dependent on:

  - `"sap.ui.unified"`
  - `"sap.ui.layout"`

This can be seen in the [source code of the `sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable` module](https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap/ui/comp/smarttable/SmartTable-dbg.js).

## Resolution

1. Ensure that no debug mode, `sap-ui-debug`, `sap-ui-xx-componentPreload` or `sap-ui-xx-libraryPreloadFiles` is active unnecessarily.
2. Enable asynchronous module loading:

   - In a *central Fiori launchpad* ("Work Zone") scenario: refer to [How to make UI5 content compatible with the FLP setting "Asynchronous Module Loading"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74959323/5846045)
   - If you can control the bootstrap config, ensure that the attribute `data-sap-ui-async="true"` exists in the served starting HTML document of the launchpad or app.
3. In the app descriptor (`manifest.json`):

   - Declare all UI5 libs that are used by the app either directly or transitively. **Note:** unless the app intends to load specific UI5 libs manually, **avoid adding `{ lazy: true }`.**
   - Enable [preloading remote model data](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/26ba6a5c1e5c417f8b21cce1411dba2c).

   ```js
   {
     // ...
     "sap.ui5": {
       "dependencies": {
         "libs": { // Avoid { lazy: true } unless the app loads the lib manually
           "sap.ui.core": {},
           "sap.m": {},
           "sap.ui.comp": {},
           "sap.ui.table": {},
           "sap.ui.unified": {},
           "sap.ui.layout": {},
           "sap.uxap": {},
           "sap.f": {},
           "sap...": {} 
         },
       },
       "models": {
         "myODataModel": {
           "preload": true,
           //...
   ```
4. After building a new `Component-preload.js` (or `library-preload.js`), deploy the optimized bundle to the target system **and**, if feasible, update the SAPUI5 resources to the latest available patch number from one of the [maintained SAPUI5 versions](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html) too since the single module load issue could've been also caused by Fiori launchpad.
5. In an ABAP system scenario:

   1. Refer to the [note 3155948 - ABAP SAPUI5 patch version update](https://me.sap.com/notes/3155948).
   2. Ensure that the app index is kept up-to-date. See the [SAP note 2364579](https://me.sap.com/notes/2364579). Otherwise, you might see the following error logged in the browser console:

      > "Error in app component *<app name>*: No descriptor was found".

      **Note:** the *app name* should match the `/sap.app/id` value from `manifest.json` in terms of case-sensitivity.
   3. Recalculate the app index (C.f. [note 2227577](https://me.sap.com/notes/2227577)) and clear the cache (C.f. [note 2319491](https://me.sap.com/notes/2319491)).

This should load the table faster since its dependencies don't need to be loaded on-demand or even synchronously which avoids freezing the UI thread (main thread) of the browser.

With `preload: true` in the `/sap.ui5/models/<model name>` section, the service `$metadata` document and annotations can be requested earlier, on which the `SmartTable` depends.

---

For other performance related best-practices, see also the topic **[Performance Checklist](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/9c6400eb7dc145b78e94a81e6e390780)**.