# How to treat bootstrap's data-sap-ui-libs vs manifest's sap.ui5/dependencies/libs?

Tags: sapui5

I usually declare all standard libraries that the application depends on in the manifest under `sap.ui5/dependencies/libs`.

Now what should I put in the bootstrap argument `data-sap-ui-libs`, the same libraries? What are the effects if I put less / more in `data-sap-ui-libs`? How do they differ?

PS. I couldn't find this in SAP's documentation, but please proof me wrong. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the effects if I put less/more in `data-sap-ui-libs`? How do they differ?

My recommendation is to remove `data-sap-ui-libs` from `index.html` altogether. **Especially** if the app is dealing with OData, it's important to retrieve the `$metadata` document as early as possible. See the example below:

### In `index.html`

```html
<head>
  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://ui5.sap.com/<version>/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon"
    data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
    data-sap-ui-async="true"
    data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
    data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "demo": "./" }'
    data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
  ></script><!-- No data-sap-ui-lib -->
</head>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
  <div style="height: 100%"
    data-sap-ui-component
    data-name="demo" 
    data-height="100%"
  ></div>
</body>
```

### In `manifest.json`

```json
{
  "sap.app": {
    "dataSources": {
      "myODataSource": {
        "uri": "/odata_org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
          "odataVersion": "2.0",
          "localUri": "model/metadata.xml",
          "annotations": [
            "annotation0"
          ]
        }
      },
      "annotation0": {
        "type": "ODataAnnotation",
        "uri": "annotation/annotation0.xml",
        "settings": {
          "localUri": "annotation/annotation0.xml"
        }
      }
    },
    "...": "..."
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    "dependencies": {
      "minUI5Version": "1.108.4",
      "libs": {
        "sap.ui.core": {},
        "sap.m": {},
        "sap.ui.table": {},
        "sap.ui.unified": {}
      }
    },
    "models": {
      "": {
        "dataSource": "myODataSource",
        "settings": {
          "preliminaryContext": true,
          "tokenHandling": false
        },
        "preload": true
      }
    },
    "...": "..."
  },
  "...": "..."
}
```

### Result

[image: OpenUI5 bootstrapping with OData data]

As you can see, the `$metadata` document is being fetched in parallel with the control libraries. This ensures that entities can be requested right away (e.g. in `$batch`) as soon as the libs are loaded. If libs were declared in `data-sap-ui-libs`, they'd be loading first, **then** the `$metadata`, **and then** the entities which creates an unnecessary bottleneck.

But even without considering OData, I noticed the page gets already a bit faster when the libs are removed from `data-sap-ui-libs`. In general, try different approaches and do performance measurements, **in addition** to documented performance guidelines, and regardless of what people say (including me).

---

## TL;DR

- Use `data-sap-ui-libs` **only if:**

  1. The app has no `Component.js` at all.
  2. Modules from libraries other than `sap.ui.core` are accessed **before creating the component** (E.g. instantiating `sap.m.Shell` as a shell for the `ComponentContainer`)
- Otherwise, remove `data-sap-ui-libs` altogether and maintain `/sap.ui5/dependencies/libs` only - **Especially** if the app is supposed to be launched from an app container such as SAP Fiori launchpad (FLP) which skips loading `index.html` altogether.

See also [What happens if a library preload file / library dependencies is not updated in the UI5-manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64900869/what-happens-if-a-library-preload-file-library-dependencies-is-not-updated-in/65323972#65323972)

Answer (score 4):

The bootstrapping (`data-sap-ui-libs`) is done in the `index.html`. It only needs to contain the libs which are referenced in the `index.html`.

If your code looks like this:

```
new sap.m.Shell({
    app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
        name: "my.namespace.app",
        height: "100%"
    })
}).placeAt("content");
```

Then you should require the following libs:

```
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.core"
```

---

If your code looks like this:

```
sap.ui.require([
    "sap/m/Shell",
    "sap/ui/core/ComponentContainer"
], function(Shell, ComponentContainer) {
    new Shell({
        app: new ComponentContainer({
           name: "my.namespace.app",
           height: "100%"
        })
     }).placeAt("content");
});
```

You don't need to require anything (but it may affect loading time of your app).

---

**All** libraries that are used in the views should be required in the `manifest.json`. So if you use `sap.m` in your app you should require it in your `manifest.json`, even if you've already required it in the `index.html`.

This is because the `Component.js` and the `manifest.json` are the default entry points for an app and the `index.html` ist just a wrapper for standalone apps outside of a Fiori Launchpad.

Comment: My code looks like your first example. As we already load sap-ui-core.js via the`src"=resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js"` there is no need to include it in the `data-sap-ui-libs`?

Comment: The JavaScript file `sap-ui-core.js` and the lib `sap.ui.core` are **not the same**! The `sap-ui-core.js` is the entry point of the UI5 framework and will load all required libs (`sap.m`, `sap.uxap`, `sap.ui.core` and many more) and dependencies (`jQuery`, `crossroads` for routing and many more).

Comment: @Pieter There is really no need to include anything in `data-sap-ui-libs` **if** there is no other library usage before creating the component (such as instantiating `sap.m.Shell` before ComponentContainer). It's true that `sap-ui-core.js` and the `sap.ui.core` lib are not the same but [UI5 makes sure that the core lib is loaded first](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/db4c5e059aca1a0d8f3ca04c9b6626a08a897f17/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Core.js#L397-L398) before any other modules are loaded. Hence, no need to include `sap.ui.core` as a dependent library.

Answer (score 0):

I would kept them declared on the manifest.

By declaring them on your .html file under the `data-sap-ui-libs`, you are basically requiring those dependencies right after the UI5 lib is loaded - even before your component is loaded.

By declaring them on your manifest, you are declaring the dependencies for your own component. So, those dependencies are only loaded before the initialization of your component.

As the component should be isolated, you component should not expect to be always used in a standalone mode.

Comment: But is there any use at all for listing additional libraries in data-sap-ui-libs apart from sap.m if the component will load the others through the manifest?

Comment: data-sap-ui-libs is just another place to declare dependencies. You might have a .html file with a UI5 app created without the use of a component where everything is declared directly in the html file itself (so there wouldn't be a manifest file). Even sap.m does not need to be loaded from the bootstrap.