# SAPUI5 show some errors for loading resource bundle when I use SmartTable

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I have a `SAPUI5` application that uses `sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable`.

I loaded needed libraries based on other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817459/how-to-load-sap-ui-comp-smarttable-smarttable-faster).

But even by adding dependencies in the `manifest.json` file like the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "minUI5Version": "1.58.0",
    "libs": {
        "sap.collaboration": {
            "minVersion": "1.58",
            "lazy": true
        },
        "sap.m": {
            "minVersion": "1.58"
        },
        "sap.ui.comp": {
            "minVersion": "1.58"
        },
        "sap.ui.core": {
            "minVersion": "1.58"
        },
        "sap.ui.unified": {
            "minVersion": "1.58"
        },
        "sap.ui.table": {
            "minVersion": "1.58"
        },
        "sap.ushell": {
            "minVersion": "1.58"
        }
    }
},
```

But it tries to load some translation files which are not exist in the `WEBIDE` SAPUI5 resources.

So I see a list of errors like what are highlighted in the following picture.

[image]

**Now the question is, how can I resolve these error messages?**

It does not cause my app to stop but I prefer to have no error when I want to present my app for the customer.

Comment: I just found this question accidentally. I remember having similar error messages even in OpenUI5. But I can't reproduce it anymore (tested with 1.58+). Seems to be fixed from the UI5 side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the i18n is not set up fully.

1.
verify the appropriate langues files exist in ur appropriate folder (standard is i18n)

- i18n.properties
- i18n_de.properties
- i18n_en.properties

2.
insert the supported languages in ur index file

**index.html**

```
data-sap-ui-xx-supportedLanguages="en,de"
```

have fun

Comment: You are right but only for the last 2 errors. But the first 5 errors are not related to my app files. They are related to the smart table dependent libraries. You can see the highlighted addresses.